# My page transition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm trying to create a full page transition using css animations. I've come to a fork in the road. I've placed a class on my link and have called it using JQuery to then apply the css class to the page to activate the transition. Now, when I assign the new window location, it wants to override the animation. It's like I can either have one or the other, not both, at least not how I'm doing it anyway...any tips?

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var linkLocation

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      linkLocation = this.href;
      redirectPage();      

    });

    function redirectPage() {
        $("body").attr('class', 'page-rotateSlideOut');
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

});
```

Comment: Instead of creating global varible it would be nice to pass parameter to function directly `redirectPage(this.href);` and `function redirectPage(linkLocation)`

Answer (score 1):

`window.location = linkLocation` will refresh the page.  That's why your transition doesn't work.

If your `.page-rotateSlideOut` style has a duration on it, you could do something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location = linkLocation; }, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout`.

Like

```
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").attr('class', 'page-rotateSlideOut');
    setTimeout(redirectPage,5000);    

});
```

Remove `$("body").attr('class', 'page-rotateSlideOut');` in `redirectPage`